# MySQL posts table handling parent items in URL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL with the following structure:

```
sequence
slug
parent
```

the URL's look like:

```
www.domain.com/slug
```

where slug = result from the database

i want to be able to redirect the user to include all the parent slug items if they visit the wrong URL

here is the code i currently have:

```
$sql="SELECT * from website_posts where slug = '".$PageID."' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$website_posts=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

$slug = '';

if($website_posts["parent"] != '') {
    $sql="SELECT * from website_posts where sequence = '".$website_posts["parent"]."' ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

    $slug.= $result["slug"].'/'.$website_posts["slug"]; 

    $loop=true;

    while($loop) {
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] != $slug) {
            $sql="SELECT * from website_posts where sequence = '".$result["parent"]."' ";
            $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
            if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
                $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

                $slug.= '/'.$result["slug"];
            } else {
                $loop=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i thought maybe creating a loop until the current URL equals the full slug but its not processing it correctly.

here is some sample data:

```
sequence    slug          parent
5553        about
5554        the-company   5553
5555        the-company2  5554
```

based on this data, the URL should be:

`domain.com/about/the-company/the-company2` but when i echo `$slug` in the above code is returning `the-company/the-company2/about`

New table structure:

```
sequence    slug          parent
5553        one
5554        two           5553
5555        three         5554
5556        four          5555
5557        five          5556
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like tree but  reversed order , you can use this

```
$slug=$PageID;
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT sequence, slug, parent FROM website_posts where slug='".$slug."'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $url=array();
    if($row){
    $url[]=$row["slug"];
        if($row["parent"]){
                $query=mysql_query("SELECT sequence, slug, parent FROM website_posts where sequence='".$row["parent"]."'");
                $r=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    while($r){ 
                    $url[]=$r["slug"];

                    if(!$r["parent"]){$r=false;}
                    else{
                        $q=mysql_query("SELECT sequence, slug, parent FROM website_posts where sequence='".$r["parent"]."'");
                    $r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
                    }
                }

        }
    }

    $url=array_reverse($url);
    //print_r($url);
    $url=implode("/", $url);
    echo $url;
```

Comment: i will try this now, i am getting a syntax error on the line that says $url=[];

Comment: i think your php version is older than php 5.4 now i will fix my answer

Comment: ah thank you thats sorted the error. will this work for multiple parent items?

Comment: yeah off course, it is tested multiple parent items. But not all spesific times

Comment: i have just changed my table rows and added one, two, three, four and five as slugs. row two onwards has parent items but its only showing up to four

Comment: i just test it for 9 parenthetical situation, and worked for me

Comment: ah yes, i got it working. i had done something wrong :) thank you so much!